# Jenkins says my reverse proxy setup is broken: but there is no proxy

Tags: jenkins

This errormessage is preventing me from updating Jenkins

```
Jenkins says my reverse proxy setup is broken
```

and:

```
Failed to resolve host name updates.jenkins.io. 
Perhaps you need to configure         HTTP proxy?

java.net.UnknownHostException: updates.jenkins.io
```

But I do not use any proxy AND I can access the page e.g. via firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the Jenkins URL configured in the System Configuration matches the URL you're using to access Jenkins.

To reach the System Configuration:

1. Go to your Jenkins page
2. Click Manage Jenkins
3. Click Configure System
4. Scroll to Jenkins Location and find Jenkins URL.

Ensure that port value matches with the port value set in the  section of the jenkins.xml file located in the Jenkins folder on your machine.

Comment: Please can you specify where exactly find "the port value set in the section of the jenkins.xml file located in the Jenkins folder on your machine"?  I am not sure how to ensure this second point - I have no jenkins.xml file in Jenkins home folder.

Answer (score -1):

During boot up, jenkins was loaded as a service. This Server started early. The time jenkins was started, the network connection was not ready. Jenkins checked only the URL once and cached the result.

```
sudo service jenkins restart
```

has made the trick to find the source of the terribly misleading error message.

**EDIT:** It does not solve the problem, but it can help you to do so. Your cause might be similar to this caching problem but the reason a total different one.

Comment: This is only a temporary fix. Configure your init system to start this service when the network is ready.

Comment: correct it's a fix, but googleling this kind of symptoms may lead to a total wrong assumption. "There is error with a proxy" ... but there is not proxy. So this answer is in total useful to bring someone on the right track. It's just saying where the error can come from too. I wanted to share this info, because it took me lot's of time. to write a sufficient answer in a single post is a challenge. So I disagree for the down vote.